# assembly reference SlimDX?

Tags: slimdx, xinput

I've looked at another post involving SlimDX and wanted to reference it in my project (for Xbox 360 Input), but after installing SlimDX, the files are nowhere to be found. I tried searching Slimdx on my whole computer, and nothing showed up. This is on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default location is: c:\program files (x86)\SlimDX SDK (version)

Comment: That was exactly where I found it. Thanks.